# How to localize iPhone(monotouch) and Windows Phone 7 application altogether?

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, windows-phone

I want to build application both for Widows Phone 7 and iPhone using .net stack.
As being rationale I want to avoid to double code this logic. Is it possible to use resx files in both platform for this, or are there any good viable solution so I can reuse code base on both platforms?

Any good advice or best practice if anyone stoped on the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [post](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2010/09/monotouch-meet-windowsphone7.html) from Craig Dunn that examines code sharing between the platforms

Comment: It's not answer to my question. I already know how to share dlls, but I'm particulary interested in localization (globalization). Nice blog post anyway, very usefull.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "localization" part of your question.  I haven't tried using resource files in MT, but here's a post that mentions it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098726/monotouch-using-embedded-resx-files-on-iphone-build

Comment: Yes, I saw that one, earlier today. Seems that I will need to do a little experiment to find out about this.